# JUnit - Test class instantiation with objects in parameters

Tags: java, class, unit-testing, junit

I am very new to JUnit testing and I am trying to understand how to test the instantiation of an class.

Let us say that I have the following `ToyBox` class which needs an `ArrayList<Toy>` in order to be instantiated. This list of toys is created on another part of the program, of course, but I do not understand very well where I should create it in order to unit test `ToyBox`.

### ToyBox Class

```
public ToyBox(ArrayList<Toy> toyList){
    this.toys= toyList;

    for (Toy toy: toyList) {
        checkToy(toy);
    }
}

private void checkToy(Toy toy){
    if (toy.isRed()){
        this.numRed += 1;
    } else {
        this.numBlue += 1;
    }
}
public int getBlues(){
    return this.numBlue;
}
```

### ToyBoxTest

```
public class ToyBoxTest {

    @Test
    public void getNumBlues() throws Exception {
        // assert that num blues corresponds
    }
```

Where should I instantiate the ToyBox class in order to perform the getNumBlues() method?

Should it be like this?

```
public class ToyBoxTest {
    ArrayList<Toy> toyList = new ArrayList<Toy>();
    Toy toy1 = new Toy("blue", "car");
    Toy toy2 = new Toy("red", "bike");
    toyList.add(toy1);
    toyList.add(toy2);

    @Test
    public void getNumBlues() throws Exception {
        // assert that num blues corresponds
        ToyBox box = new ToyBox(toyList);
        assertEquals(1, box.getBlues());
    }
```

Basically, my question is where and how should I create the arraylist of objects needed to test a class that depends on that created list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most tutorials will state that the best practice is to instantiate the object you're about to test in a setup method (a `@Before` method in JUnit's terminology). However, your usecase doesn't fit this pattern well. As your constructor holds all the logic, you should instantiate the object **in the test** itself, and then assert that `getNumBlues()` and `getNumReds()` return the correct results. E.g.:

```
@Test
public void bothColors() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Toy> toyList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList
        new Toy("blue", "car"),
        new Toy("red", "bike"));
    ToyBox box = new ToyBox(toyList);
    assertEquals(1, box.getBlues());
}

@Test
public void justBlues() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Toy> toyList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList
        new Toy("blue", "car"),
        new Toy("blue", "bike"));
    ToyBox box = new ToyBox(toyList);
    assertEquals(2, box.getBlues());
}

// etc...
```